# Почему возникает ошибка с установкой локально сервера?

Tags: php, apache, установка

Установил локальный серер Apache mySQL PHP 5.6.18  вроде все запустилось но не ставится композер выдает ошибку

```
    The PHP exe file you specified did not execute correctly: 
C:\Server\bin\PHP\php.exe

Running it from the command line might highlight the problem.
Internal Error [ERR_INVALID], exit code 0
```

попытался запустить php.exe через командную строку выдает ошибку

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\Server\bin\PHP\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\Server\bin\PHP\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\Server\bin\PHP\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\Server\bin\PHP\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Закоментируй сторочки в  php.ini где подключаются модули php_pdo_firebird и php_pdo_oci  Что-то с ними не так.

Comment: а что может быть не то. Я итак закоментил.